# SWT GridLayout inside ScrolledComposite messing up the size of the components

Tags: java, swt

I have a window that must show a list of buttons all below each other.
All buttons must be square of a specific size (size can change while running).

This simple example works as in it shows all the buttons.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        val scrollPanel = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);
        scrollPanel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        scrollPanel.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        val gridPanel = new Composite(scrollPanel, SWT.NONE);
        val gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        gridPanel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        gridPanel.setLayout(gridLayout);
        scrollPanel.setContent(gridPanel);

        val blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
        val red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
        scrollPanel.setBackground(blue);
        gridPanel.setBackground(red);

        val exitButton = new Button(gridPanel, SWT.PUSH);
        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        exitButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, touchEvent -> shell.dispose());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            val button = new Button(gridPanel, SWT.PUSH);
            button.setText("Item: " + i);
            button.setSize(60, 60);
            gridPanel.setSize(gridPanel.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        }

        shell.setSize(100, 700);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

However, whenever I do the gridPanel.computeSize(), the buttons lose their size that is set by button.setSize().

When I remove the gridPanel.setSize() after adding a button, the size will be 0 and the gridPanel is never shown at all.

When I set the gridLayout on the scrollPanel and add the buttons to that, then only one button is shown.
(The last button if I use setContent() and the second (for whatever reason) if I do not use setContent() and just rely on the constructor of the buttons.)

At this moment, I am quite out of my options so if anyone can clear something up of this scenario, then please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `setSize` is only going to work properly when you are not using layouts (absolute positioning).

If you are using a layout, it will automatically set the components size based on the layout itself and how you define the layout data of the components.

In general, it is highly recommended to use layouts over absolute positioning.

In case of `GridLayout`, you can specify a component size via `widthHint` and `heightHint` in its `GridData`, for example:

```
Button button = new Button(gridPanel, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Item: " + i);
GridData buttonLayoutData = new GridData();
buttonLayoutData.widthHint = 60;
buttonLayoutData.heightHint = 60;
button.setLayoutData(buttonLayoutData);
```

Other observations:

- to make the `ScrollComposite` work properly you should add these lines:

  ```
  scrollPanel.setExpandHorizontal(true);
  scrollPanel.setExpandVertical(true);
  scrollPanel.setMinSize(gridPanel.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
  ```

  in particular, `setMinSize` will tell the `ScrollComposite` at what size it should make the scrollbar appear.
- if the parent layout is a `FillLayout` you should not set layout data on its children. It won't do anything since it is not expected. So you should remove the `setLayoutData` from `scrollPanel` and `gridPanel`.
- if you want to change the button size at a later moment, just get its layout data, modify the hints and ask the component to layout (also don't forget to notify the scrollbar of the change with `setMinSize`):

  ```
  GridData buttonLayoutData = (GridData) button.getLayoutData();
  buttonLayoutData.widthHint = 40;
  buttonLayoutData.heightHint = 40;
  button.requestLayout();
  scrollPanel.setMinSize(gridPanel.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
  ```

Comment: Is it a better idea to remove/replace the FillLayout or remove the layout data from the scroll-/grid-Panel? I put the FillLayout on the shell and scrollPanel because nothing was showing at the time... and I was desperate :D

Comment: `GridData` is needed only if the parent layout is `GridLayout`. If you just want the content to fill all the available space,  then `FillLayout` is the perfect choice. It seems appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a layout (which you should), you must not use `setSize()` or otherwise interfere with the layout.

Use `widthHint` and `heightHint` of `GridData` instead to control the size of the buttons.

For example:

```
GridData gridData = new GridData( SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false );
gridData.widthHint = 60;
gridData.heightHint = 60;
button.setLayoutData( gridData );
```